# Key error in dictionary when try to add a list element

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to add a count in a dictionary that has this final restructure: `{'stationA':[2,3], 'stationB':[1,0]}`

```
 if start_station_name not in my_station_dict:
                my_station_dict["station_name"]=start_station_name
                my_station_dict[start_station_name][0]=0
 my_station_dict[start_station_name][0] += 1

 if stop_station_name not in my_station_dict:
            my_station_dict["station_name"] = stop_station_name
            my_station_dict[stop_station_name][1] = 0
 my_station_dict[stop_station_name][1] += 1
```

But I get

```
my_station_dict[start_station_name][0]=0
KeyError: 'N 6 St & Bedford Ave'
```

Comment: You need to initialize that element of the dict as a list before you can assign to an element of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_station_dict["station_name"]=start_station_name
```

You are adding "station_name" as a key in your dict, but then trying to access it using the key start_station_name.  To be clear, your code is creating this:

```
{'station_name': 'N 6 St & Bedford Ave'}
```

When you really want this:

```
{'N 6 St & Bedford Ave': [0, 0]}
```

It's a simple update:

```
if start_station_name not in my_station_dict:
    my_station_dict[start_station_name] = [0, 0]
my_station_dict[start_station_name][0] += 1

if stop_station_name not in my_station_dict:
    my_station_dict[stop_station_name] = [0, 0]
my_station_dict[stop_station_name][1] += 1
```

Comment: I need to count two values (when the station is the start_station and when is the stop_station

Comment: Ok, I didn't catch that.  Updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what I think you're asking:

```py
my_station_dict = {}

def foo(start_station_name, stop_station_name):
    if start_station_name not in my_station_dict:
        my_station_dict[start_station_name]=[0]*2
    my_station_dict[start_station_name][0] += 1

    if stop_station_name not in my_station_dict:
        my_station_dict[stop_station_name]=[0]*2
    my_station_dict[stop_station_name][1] += 1

trips = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'B']]
for start, stop in trips:
    foo(start, stop)

print(my_station_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [3, 0], 'B': [1, 2], 'C': [0, 2], 'D': [1, 1]}
```